# Rename python key dynamically inside of values

Tags: python, django

I need to change the "key" of my data when it outputs.

I am unsure if django can do this. FWIW, this outputs to elastic search (not sure that is relevant).

Basically it comes out with `{"level":1 }` but I want it to say `{"level_1":1}` instead.

How can this be achieved? Here is my current code

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    def indexing(self):
        obj = TaskIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            title=self.title,
            tag=list(self.tag.values('name').annotate(level=F('level_%)))
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

**How result looks:**

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"Test item",
      "tag":[  
         {  
            "name":"Nope",
            "level":1
         },
         {  
            "name":"Yep",
            "level":2
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

**How I want the result to look:**

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"Test item",
      "tag":[  
         {  
            "name":"Nope",
            "level_1":1
         },
         {  
            "name":"Yep",
            "level_2":2
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

**Search.py**

```
class TaskIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'task-index'

# Bulk indexing function, run in shell
def bulk_indexing():
    TaskIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Task.objects.all().iterator()))

# Simple search function
def _search(title):
    s = Search().filter('term', title=title.text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

Comment: How about just adding the new key to the dictionary instead of trying to rename keys?

Comment: Because the searchkit library I'm using only looks at keynames.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with elastic search or the indexing function you are doing but maybe some kind of function that will format the data will do?

```
def format_dict(data):
    for obj in data:
        new_tags = []
        for tag in obj.get('tag', []):
            level_number = tag['level']
            tag.pop('level')
            tag['level_%s' % level_number] = level_number
            new_tags.append(tag)
        obj['tag'] = new_tags
    return data
```

Then using it in your code

`return format_dict(obj.to_dict(include_meta=True))`

At least this works when i run it with some test data like so

`print(format_dict([{"title": "Test item", "tag": [{"name": "Nope", "level": 1}, {"name": "Yep", "level": 2}], }]))`

Comment: Where would this code belong- in my models.py to replace the def indexing function? I've added my search.py for completness

Comment: Youre answer does not work. It should read "level_1" . I've updated my answer, an attempt using "annotate". Could you please try again?